# Excluding files and folders during plugin publishing

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I want to exclude `.svn` folders when I publish my plugin to our custom Artifactory repository. I'm assuming the inclusion of `.svn` folders is the issue based on the error strack trace provided below.

I'm publishing using the following command:

`gradlew artifactoryPublish --stacktrace`

This is the publishing block in `build.gradle`:

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = artifactory_context
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'plugins-release-local'
            username = artifactory_user
            password = artifactory_password
            maven = true

        }
        defaults {
            publications ('mavenJava')
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

This is the stack trace I get when I attempt to publish, notice the attempt copy of `.svn/entries` to `assets/entries`.

```
...
:copyAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':copyAssets'.
> Could not copy file '/u01/var/build/pluginXYZ/grails-app/assets/.svn/entries' to '/u01/var/build/pluginXYZ/build/resources/main/META-INF/assets/entries'.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':copyAssets'.
...
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not copy file '/u01/var/build/pluginXYZ/grails-app/assets/.svn/entries' to '/u01/var/build/pluginXYZ/build/resources/main/META-INF/assets/entries'.
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /u01/var/build/pluginXYZ/build/resources/main/META-INF/assets/entries (Permission denied)
... 80 more
```

The permission on `entries` (both trees) are `-r--r--r--`.

If I exclude those folders, I should get rid of said permission issue. The first checkout will always publish, but subsequent publishes (say after an update), fail with this error.

**Update #2**

Here are the three combination I tried without success:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
                //first attempt
                //exclude("**/.svn/**")
                //second attempt
                //exclude{ details -> details.file.name.contains(".svn") }
                //third attempt
                //exclude "**/.svn/**"
        }
    }
}
```

The error output when publishing, using all three attempts, is the following:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method exclude() for arguments [build_3nsvrqvwahy23ir3fxdj970id$_run_closure7_closure13_closure14_closure15@10e9a5fe] on org.gradlpublish.maven.internal.publication.DefaultMavenPublication_Decorated@ca7e37f.
```

**Update #3**

I found the following link [taking about excluding files](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/gradle-beyond-the/9781449373801/ch01.html).

I then adjusted my `gradle.build` to this:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java {
                        exclude "**/.svn/**"
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Same error.

**Update #4**

More attempts... same results

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact sourceJar{
                exclude '**/.svn/**'
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact  exclude '**/.svn/**'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I appended the following at the root level in my `build.gradle` and it seems to work:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      exclude '**/.svn/**'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Say, you have a file which you want to avoid *ONLY* while publishing to the repository. If you go with as suggested by @TekiusFanatikus

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      exclude '**/.svn/**'
    }
  }
}
```

you will be able to achieve it but this will also exclude the file/folder etc. from the artifact that you generate using *gradle build*.

Instead, I would recommend to use the approach as mentioned here [gradle documnetation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#N141C5)

You can create a task which have your desired exclusion applied

```
task apiJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName "publishing-api"
    from sourceSets.main.output
    exclude '**/.svn/**'
}
```

and then refer the task while publishing.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        api(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'org.gradle.sample'
            artifactId 'project2-api'
            version '2'

            artifact apiJar
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the jar that gets published will not have .svn folder. The point that I wanted to make here is that it will not touch your artifact that gets created using *gradle build*. It will still have your .svn folder.

But if you want it to be removed from both the places, then the best option is as suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to extend on @Neeraj answer. The problem with the custom JAR approach is that it doesn't produce a valid POM -- especially not in the case of multi-module projects -- unlike the `from components.java` approach which generates a POM correctly.

In order to overcome this, we could declare two publications - one internal used only to generate a POM, and the second is the actual publication we wish to publish (without the excluded files):

```
task apiJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName "publishing-api"
    from sourceSets.main.output
    exclude '**/.svn/**'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        def pomString = null

        internal(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            pom.withXml {
                pomString = asString().toString()
            }
        }

        api(MavenPublication) {
            artifact apiJar
            pom.withXml {
                def builder = asString()
                builder.delete(0, builder.length())
                builder.append(pomString)
            }
        }
    }
}

generatePomFileForApiPublication.dependsOn(generatePomFileForInternalPublication)

artifactoryPublish {
    publications('api')
}
```

Note that the names of the `generatePomFileForXPublication` tasks are determined according to the names of the publications.

---

**Old Answer**

This is my previous attempt at generating a POM manually, but it is not nearly as complete as the newer answer above.

```
task apiJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName "publishing-api"
    from sourceSets.main.output
    exclude '**/.svn/**'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        api(MavenPublication) {
            artifact apiJar

            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode("dependencies")
                project.configurations.runtimeClasspath.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies.forEach { d ->
                    def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode("dependency")
                    dependencyNode.appendNode("groupId", d.moduleGroup)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode("artifactId", d.moduleName)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode("version", d.moduleVersion)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

artifactoryPublish {
    publications('api')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use 'exclude' method with filefilter. Just add it under 'from' in publications block.

Comment: I've tried 3 different configuration (See update 2) without success. Not sure if I implemented what you had in mind.

Comment: It looks like your components.java is wrong try specifying the artifact explicitly like artifact file("path-to-jar/jar.jar").

Comment: Not by any chance you could pseudo code something for me? So far, any attempts to append artifact with exclude, brings up the same error.